# iOS XMPP Framwork - libidn.a does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, bitcode

XMPP Framework Error

ld: 'xmppFrameWork/Vendor/libidn/libidn.a(stringprep.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

Note: Error occurred, while running app in iPhone device only. (It's working in simulator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are enabling `bitcode` in your project, all your libraries including external libraries should be built by enabling bitcode.In your case `xmppFrameWork` is not enabled for bitcode. So what you can do is disable the `bitcode` in your project settings or get an updated version of above library with bitcode enabled.[image]